# physical folders are showing query string

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-routing

I am creating my own MVC framework in php. all work good but when putting some of physical folder in addressbar `http://localhost/mvc/view` it showing `http://localhost/mvc/view/?url=view` but not in `http://localhost/mvc/model`. model also a physical folder but not showing any query string.

**htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

what's wrong?

Comment: can you paste the full url that you are trying to access?

Comment: ya i have edit it. please check

Comment: is view the "physical" folder?

Comment: yes both are physical folder but one have the problem but another one not.

Comment: you're using only one .htaccess file right?

Comment: Can you give folder and file structure ?

Answer (score 0):

You are sure the mod_rewrite is on?

Check in your apache.conf file is uncoment line:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

if is uncoment and you are 100% sure is on check your vhost config include AllowOverride

```
<Directory "location/where/is/index">
  AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: yes my dear. this is not first time i am working with mvc. but this is the first time i face this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may have some conflicting rule OR else a `.htaccess` in `/model/` or `/view/` folders.

In any case try inserting this on top of your current .htaccess:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```